# Datetime Error: Time data does not match

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to create date time functions using the following code:

```
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/1960 0:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2000 0:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: time data '1/1/1960 0:00 AM' does not match format
>   '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'

I would appreciate help with this as I have tried tweaking the parameters to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0:00 AM` doesn't match `%I:%M %p`, because `%I` [doesn't include the hour `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), just `1` to `12` like on an analogue clock face:

> `%I` Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.    `01, 02, ..., 12`

Midnight in a 12-hour clock is `12:00 AM`:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('1/1/1960 12:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Ah, right, not the padding, `0` is indeed not a valid time in a 12-hour clock. I've seen this before, probably a dupe.

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked well!